# Javascript Quiz - How to tally score from answers in multiple select elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm unable to write a loop to tally the score of a quiz I've created for my wordpress site.

The quiz style is 'match items in column A with items in Column B'.

Column B items use a select element to match the corresponding item from Column A.

The best I can come up with is manually adding each selected answer together like so..

html

```
<select id="testValues1">
    <option value="right">a</option>
    <option value="wrong">b</option>
    <option value="wrong">c</option>
</select>
<select id="testValues2">
    <option value="wrong">a</option>
    <option value="right">b</option>
    <option value="wrong">c</option>
</select>
<select id="testValues3">
    <option value="wrong">a</option>
    <option value="wrong">b</option>
    <option value="right">c</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="finalScore()">Submit</button>

<div id="scoreDisplay">score goes here</div>
```

javascript

```
<script>
function finalScore(){
var i = 0;
var select1 = document.getElementById("testValues1");
var answer1 = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer1 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select2 = document.getElementById("testValues2");
var answer2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer2 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

var select3 = document.getElementById("testValues3");
var answer3 = select3.options[select3.selectedIndex].value;
    if(answer3 == "right"){
        i++;
    }

document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = i;
}
</script>
```

The above works well enough but I want to add a few more quizzes like this, some with more than 3 possible questions/matchups.

My ideas for it that I have been unable to code..

javascript

```
function finalScore() {
    var answersCorrect = 0;
    var answersCounter = 0;
    foreach "select" {
        var rightOrWrong = "get value";
        if (rightOrWrong = right) {
            answersCorrect++
        }
        answersCounter++;
    }
    var finalScore = Math.floor((answersCorrect / answersCounter) * 100));
    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = finalScore;
}
```

A solution doesn't have to be pure javascript, if it's not possible, but I'm even less well versed in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following function will make your quiz code more reusable.  It takes into account the number of questions when calculating the percentage of correct answers. In order to add a question you will just have add the class question to each of select statements that will become a question.

live demo: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/ZQrKjY

```
function finalScore(){//begin function

  //initialize the correct variable
  var correct = 0;

  var selectValue;

  //store the collection of elements with the class name question
  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

  //the number of questions(elements with a class name of question)
  var numOfQuestions = questions.length;

//loop through the collection of elements with a question class
for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++ ){//begin for loop

 //get the value of the select element
 selectValue =  questions[i].options[questions[i].selectedIndex].value;

  //if the value equals right
  if(selectValue === "right"){//begin if then

    //increment the correct variable
    correct++;

  }//end if then

}//end for loop

//get the percentage of correct answers
document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = (100/numOfQuestions) * correct;  

}//end function
```

HTML(note the addition of the class question to each select statement):

```
     <select class ="question" id="testValues1">
       <option value="right">a</option>
       <option value="wrong">b</option>
       <option value="wrong">c</option>
    </select>
    <select class="question" id="testValues2">
       <option value="wrong">a</option>
       <option value="right">b</option>
       <option value="wrong">c</option>
    </select>
    <select class="question" id="testValues3">
       <option value="wrong">a</option>
       <option value="wrong">b</option>
       <option value="right">c</option>
    </select>

<button type="button" onclick="finalScore()">Submit</button>

<div id="scoreDisplay">score goes here</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work perfect! You took into account that my number of questions will vary so I can load this script site wide and no need for id's. Thanks very much Larry!

Comment: Here's a tweaked version with percentage rounding for anybody who is interested.. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/0Lb3tLqo/4/

Comment: Not a problem, I am glad I could help.

Comment: I should make note for others that I used Larry's original pen as he was working on his newest update. The original selected each 'select' with `var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");` and has since been changed to select each 'select' by class. Both are what I was fiddling with all day and can make use of either as it eliminates the need to find the id's or even the need to have id's in the html.

Comment: Good point, Hastig, If you use the version using getElementsByClassName() function then you will be able to use other select elements on your page without skewing your results. This might be helpful if you load different quizzes for example by selecting them from a drop down list(select element).  You will have to let me know how your quiz app turns out http://bytewarestudios.com

Answer (score 1):

with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rightAnswers = 0;
    $("select").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()=='right'){ 
            rightAnswers++;    
        }
    });
    alert('right answers: ' + rightAnswers);
});
```